# how can I make this date logic more generic? flip string every n [timeunit]

Tags: javascript, date

I have the following:

```
const d = new Date();
const data = `${d.getFullYear()}-${d.getMonth()}-${d.getDay()}-${d.getHours()}-${d.getMinutes()>30?30:0}`
```

Effectively this gives a new string every 30 min.

I was thinking how to do this by passing a amount and having the same effect for [n] seconds/minutes

I tried to use getTime() but I am stuck so far. That approach gives me a whole number which I found no way to workout the same logic as above.

Any ideas how I can achieve that?

Comment: So you need a function that takes the amount, a unit of time (second or minute) and a date, then returns that date, with that time unit changed to 0, or the amount?

Comment: the code above will give me a different date string if the current date minutes are different from 30 minutes. So I want to have the same logic but in a more generic way. let say I want to switch 30min to days or months. this can be done with check the amount given and flipping the values instead of minutes to a higher unit but I hope you get my point. ex: getDatethingy(1440/*minutes*/) //[year]-[month]-[day] or getDatethingy(43800/*minutes*/) //[year]-[month]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you don't care about the contents of the string, just want it to be unique within the interval. You can divide timestamp by the interval you want the string to be the same.

```js
function dateKey(intervalMs) {
  return (Date.now() / intervalMs | 0).toString();
}

function dateKeySeconds(intervalSec) {
  return dateKey(intervalSec * 1000)
}

function dateKeyMinutes(intervalMin) {
  return dateKey(intervalMin * 60 * 1000)
}

// This will log new string every 30 seconds
setInterval(() => {
  console.log(dateKeySeconds(30))
}, 10000)
```

Comment: `Date.now() / intervalMs | 0` will cause a zero division error in case of `intervalMs` is being a falsy value.

Comment: @Eldar `intervalMs` expected to be positive integer number. Also `|` is not `||` it is bit-wise or operator to truncate decimal part.

Comment: You mean to expect  `const a = undefined | 0` not equal to 0 @yury-tarabanko?

Comment: Why? Division has priority over bitwise OR. Again the expression is `(Date.now() / intervalMs) | 0`. `|` is not for null or undefined coalescing it is **BITWISE OR** to truncate decimal part.